# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException - Connection Timed out

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle, twilio-api

I am new to spring, I have been working with twilio library for verification, while the project is building locally successfully, it fails to build on the server and throws this error each time

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'routes': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'twilioService'; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TwilioService': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Connect to verify.twilio.com:443 [verify.twilio.com/3.214.112.227, verify.twilio.com/52.20.104.111, verify.twilio.com/54.145.6.147, verify.twilio.com/34.227.179.12, verify.twilio.com/54.204.149.76, verify.twilio.com/52.2.204.41] 

failed: connect timed out
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
```

my init looks like this:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Twilio.init(env.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID_PROP),
                env.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN_PROP));
        service = Service.fetcher(env.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.TWILIO_SERVICE_SID_PROP)).fetch();
    }
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
    <version>8.26.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This looks like firewall/networking issue on the server. Can you login into the server and try to wget or curl https://verify.twilio.com ?

Comment: protocol I used is tcp and enabled HTTPS on *.twilio.com permanently. Do you think I have to enable it on HTTP as well ?

Comment: No but still believe it is networking issue from the server. Were you able to login and GET the URL?